# PHPUnit: mock all functions except one in ZendFramework2 Controller

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I need to mock a zf2 controller and keep one real function: "getStopWords".
I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10924398/phpunit-mock-all-methods-except-some) adapted below:

```
public function createMockExecpt()
{
    // create mock to get names of all functions
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('Controller\CollectionsController')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();
    $reflection = new MyReflectionClass($mock);
    $functionsToMock = $reflection->getAllfunctionNamesExcept(["getStopWords"]);

    // create mock but don't mock one function
    return $this->getMock('Controller\CollectionsController', $functionsToMock);
}
```

but got an error about redefining a class.

```
// Cannot redeclare Mock_CollectionsController_d61a5651::__clone()
```

I think this happens because I need an instance of the controller to find out all the functions it has. However I can't make an instance of the controller in this context, which is why I need a mock. But I can't make more than one mock of a class within the same test, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I thought you need an instance of the class to get all the methods.
Turns out all you need is the class name!

```
public function testGetStopWords()
{
    // get the class methods the controller has, except getStopWords
    $methodsToMock = array_diff(
        get_class_methods("Controller\CollectionsController"), 
        ["getStopWords"]
    );

    // use setMethods to determine which methods to mock
    $mockController = $this->getMockBuilder("Controller\CollectionsController")
            ->setMethods($methodsToMock)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
}
```